# Get opposite structure field in C++

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Let us suppose I have the following structs:

```
struct Point
{double _x, _y;};
struct Segment
{Point _p1, _p2;};
typedef Point Segment::* const SegmentEnd;
```

And now I would like to introduce the function which would scale the segment with relation to the `SegmentEnd` provided. That means change coordinates of the opposite to the provided `SegmentEnd`. How can I do it?

Here is the code I made to change the provided `SegmentEnd`, but I need to change the opposite one:

```
void scale(Segment& segment, SegmentEnd end, const double& scaleVal)
{
    Point& p(segment.*end);
    p._x = scaleVal*p._x;
    p._y = scaleVal*p._y;
}
```

Comment: Then send in the opposite one as argument? I think you need to explain what you try to achieve and what your problem is in more detail.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your use of pointer-to-member is awkward, where is the problem to call `scale(segment, &Segment::_p2, 2.0)` if you don't want to scale on `_p1`? You decide on which point to scale by giving it to the function, that's the whole point of using the pointer-to-member there.

Comment: What does it exactly mean "opposite to the provided SegmentEnd"? So if you pass the _p2, you want to change the _p1? Then pass the one you want to change ...

Comment: You can compare `end` with `&Segment::_p1` to know which of the two end points it refers to. You can also compare `&p` with `&end._p1`. But at that point, you have to ask yourself if using pointers to members is still worth it? You could just have a bool or enum and make the code easier to maintain.

Comment: @hobb, it is just as in a math. I scale the segment with respect to an end. I can not send the opposite end, I need to get the opposite given another end somehow.

Comment: Send in both ends (the first the one to scale, the other to use in the calculation) if you stubbornly want to use the obfuscating operator. Otherwise just send in the segment and an enum or bool indicating which end to operate on.

Comment: In my opinion the way you try to solve a problem here seems strange. Why do you try to do it *that* way others already have asked. Is this a homework question or are you dealing with legacy code?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, it is a homework.

Comment: Then I'd like to see the original task / question of that homework and what you have tried so far. There are also some help pages that have to do with asking homework questions, [here (a little general)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [here (verbose)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, the task is to scale the Segment with respect to the point of the segment provided (there are only two points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function that returns the other end:

```
SegmentEnd opposite(SegmentEnd e)
{
    return e == &Segment::_p1 ? &Segment::_p2 : &Segment::_p1;
}

// ...
Point& one(segment.*end);
Point& other(segment.*opposite(end));
```

Comment: Oh! Great! I can override negation operator `!`... Cool.

Comment: Why does not it allow to create the following method in the `.h` file? `SegmentEnd operator!(SegmentEnd);`

Comment: @cutmedown: you can, _for user-defined types_. Which pointers aren't.

Comment: @MSalters, did you mean I can **not** ?

Comment: Not in this case. SegmentEnd is only a name, for a pointer type. So it is not user-defined and you can't overload operators. In particular, its operator! Is the not-null operator

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking for is to get access the other member (the one you did NOT provide as argument), you could probably do something with comparing addresses of the element you sent in with, say _p1, and if that matches you know you want to access _p2 instead etc. But you should really solve your problem in another way if you want the least bit of readability.

I have never come across a situation where the pointer-to-member access operators could have improved my code and I am confident that will not change by reading your post here.

Edit:
So the alternative answer is in the comments of the question (ninjad by Francois), use an enum or bool argument to tell which end to operate on.

Comment: Opinion, not an answer.

Comment: @MSalters, Yes it is. It is exactly the same answer as molbdnilo has given but with some additional advise why that is probably a bad idea.

Comment: I feel this could be a good answer if some code would be shown.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18171739)

Comment: @user35443 This is the answer part: "you could probably do something with comparing addresses of the element you sent in with, say _p1, and if that matches you know you want to access _p2 instead etc." If you still feel this is not an answer to the question I would say that is your 'opinion'.

Comment: @hobb This was an automated review-queue response. Your answers are being reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply do something like:

```
void scale(Segment& segment, bool inverted, const double& scaleVal)
{
    if (!inverted) {
        // scale segment._p1 with respect to segment._p2
    } else {
        // scale segment._p2 with respect to segment._p1
    }
}
```

Then you do not even need to fiddle with the pointers to members.

The param could be an enum ("direction") as well, etc.

You could argue that with the pointer to member you expect to save the branch, but in your case it is not really the case, because you still need to check the addresses to determine which point has been sent.

You could save the branch by providing both points, the scaled one and the other as reference:

```
void scale(Segment& segment, SegmentEnd scaled, SegmentEnd reference, const double& scaleVal)
{
    // scale segment.*scaled with reflect to segment.*reference
}
```

and call appropriately:

```
scale(segment, Segment::_p1, Segment::_p2, value);
scale(segment, Segment::_p2, Segment::_p1, value);
```

(or to pass the points directly in that case)